# Nexus 3 configuration issue with public repository

Tags: nexus

In evaluating nexus 3 repository, i found the public repository is not created by default. Also, the uri content/groups/public has disappeared. How can I configured it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a "public" group manually if that is what you need.

You can get it to show up on /content/groups/public by enabling support for legacy URLs:

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/upgrading.html#_after_the_upgrade

You may also need to change the context path of the server to "/nexus" if that is what you had in Nexus 2:

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/install.html#config-context-path